# Having trouble transferring my spotipy API python code from local device to cloud based system

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, cloud, spotipy

I'm completely brand new to python. I have a little Matlab coding experience, but really nothing too intense, so I'm a pretty inexperienced coder. So far I've gotten by on youtube videos and other forum posts, but I think I need some help for my scenario.

I'm not gonna go to into detail, but essentially Spotify's reporting system on user created playlists is completely broken, and users can spam reports of it to get the title, description and image of the playlist removed. I have been hit very hard by this as I have a fairly high profile playlist and can barely keep up (get struck about 20 times a day recently). Spotify is aware of the error, but from what I can tell, it won't get fixed anytime soon, as I've dug through forums and this has been going on for others for years. Because of this, I'm trying to code something that I can run every minute or 5 minutes or so to automatically fix my playlist's data without having to check my emails or app, see I was reported, and fix it myself.

I created a code that works locally, and I'll post that below, but I'm running into a snag when trying to move to some sort of cloud based server like AWS lambda, google cloud, or Wayscript. If I run the code on my computer's terminal, the code runs and completes what I need immediately, no issues at all. When I try to move it to one of those sites, I can't get it to complete and have no idea what could be going wrong. I've messed with increasing timeout time and cpu usage on AWS, but even at 4 GB and 60 seconds (the max I've tried), it still won't complete. I'm honestly baffled, because it seems like really basic code (and obviously works on my local device without issues), so would love to know if anyone knows a solution. Here is the code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as util
import json

scope = 'playlist-modify-public ugc-image-upload'
username = 'myusername'


token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id='myclientid',client_secret='myclientsecret',redirect_uri='myredirect')
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

playlist_name = "myplaylist"
playlist_description = "my description"
id = "spotify:playlist:myid"
image = 'bit64image'

spotifyObject.user_playlist_change_details(user=username,playlist_id=id,name=playlist_name,public=True,collaborative=None,description=playlist_description)
spotifyObject.playlist_upload_cover_image(playlist_id=id,image_b64=image)


print("Playlist updated")
```

I've tried by using both the util and the OAuth with environment variables for my ID, Secret, and URI, and neither seems to work. Maybe it has something to do with the spotipy module, but I zipped it and added it to AWS layers, installed it on google cloud, and it's built in already to Wayscript, so I don't think that's the issue. It's also very strange that it seems to be the same issue in that the script never completes on all 3 services. Let me know if you have any suggestions. This has been such an annoying project so would love if someone were able to help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So dont know if this will work, but what you could try is copying over the cache file to the remote directory where your script is and see if it works then.

Look in the local directory where you ran your script for a .cache file (Tick 'Show Hidden Files' if you need to.)

If you open the .cache file in your text editor, you'll see something about access tokens, refresh tokens etc. Think Spotipy needs all that to run, either locally or remotely.

Have a feeling this is at the root of your problem, could be wrong, but do give it a shot! :)

Comment: I do believe you're right that that was the root of the problem. I attempted messing with the cache yesterday, and still had no luck. Anyway, I thankfully found a blog post that deployed "serverless" and was able to apply my code to aws lambda from my terminal. That successfully got it up and running for me.

Comment: Yes copying the `.cache` file worked, but it feels a bit clumsy. @nminto what is the blog post to deploy "serverless" ...?